# Can maven surefire plugin run multiple test executions when invoked directly? (Sonar + Jenkins not running all unit tests)

Tags: unit-testing, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven project that uses the surefire plugin for unit testing. Currently the testing is split into two executions *default-test* and *unitTests*, both bound to the *test* goal, as follows:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <!-- Test one set of files -->
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes> ... </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <!-- Test a different set of files -->
      <execution>
        <id>unitTests</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes> ... </includes>
        </configuration>
      <execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This works fine when running `mvn test`:

```
$ mvn test
...
[INFO] maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test (default-test)
...
[INFO] maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test (unitTests)
```

I am using the Sonar plugin on Jenkins to generate code metrics, and Jenkins is set up as follows:

- run the build action `mvn clean install -DskipTests`
- run the Sonar plugin as a post-build action

This means that the Sonar plugin runs the unit tests, and the unit tests are run once only. And I see the following output when the Sonar plugin runs:

```
[INFO] maven-surefire-plugin:213:test (default-cli)
```

Note that only the *default-cli* execution is invoked rather than *default-test* + *unitTests*, because (I assume) the surefire plugin is invoked directly via `mvn surefire:test` instead of via the `mvn test` lifecycle.

I can add a *default-cli* execution to the POM file, and copy the configuration from the *default-test* execution, but this will only run one set of unit tests. The unit tests configured in the `unitTests` execution are not run at all, even though that execution is bound to the same goal.

How can I ensure that the both the *default-cli* and *unitTests* executions are invoked when the Sonar plugin invokes `mvn surefire:test` ?

I am thinking that perhaps my Jenkins setup should change, so that the unit tests are run in the normal build action, which generates code coverage reports, and then the Sonar plugin runs as a post-build action and loads these reports to perform analysis. Not sure if this is possible, or what changes are required to my POM files to support this (hoping to make minimal changes to POM files is another goal).

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking that perhaps my Jenkins setup should change, so that the
>   unit tests are run in the normal build action, which generates code
>   coverage reports, and then the Sonar plugin runs as a post-build
>   action and loads these reports to perform analysis.

That seems like a good idea. You could use [maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to do this. You can configure the surefire plugin in different profiles and make the one you want your tools to use active by default.

Comment: I had a similar issue recently, and this is the pom now: https://github.com/CROSSINGTUD/WPDS/blob/master/boomerangPDS/pom.xml